# ESRI Raster Caculator - CON

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have two raster surfaces that have the same resolution and footprint.

They represent two soil layers.  As such, one should always be less than the other because that soil layer can't cross above the other.

Grid1 should always be "above" Grid2.

But my raster data don't reflect that so what I want to do is identify all pixels of Girid2 where Grid2 > Grid1 and replace them with the Grid1 values.

The desired result is a modified version of Grid2 that will be equal to Grid1 where it used to be greater than Grid1. The two surface will "kiss" in those spots.

this is what I'm trying but it doesn't appear to work

`Con("Grid2">"Grid1","Grid1","Grid2")`

I want it to evaluate as:

Where Grid2 > Grid1, replace with Grid1, otherwise keep Grid2

Comment: Use the [minimum cell statistic.](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=5009&pid=5007&topicname=Cell_Statistics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With more trials I got it work in a clean new .MXD document:

Con("Grid1"<"Grid2","Grid1","Grid2")

[image]